# Rows to Columns using visual basic

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Final
    Dim objConnection As New SqlConnection _
    ("server=localhost;database=Starbulk;Integrated Security=true;")
    Dim Table_1 As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim list As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim Table_1_reader As SqlDataReader
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Submit_ID As Integer
        Dim Form_ID As Integer
        Dim Control_ID As Integer
        Dim Row_NO As Integer
        Dim Table_ID As Integer
        Dim Int_Val As Integer
        Dim Decimal_Val As Decimal
        Dim String_Val As String
        Dim Boolean_Val As Integer
        Table_1.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()
        Table_1.SelectCommand.Connection = objConnection
        Table_1.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table_1 ORDER BY Submit_ID , Control_ID"
        Table_1.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        objConnection.Open()
        Table_1_reader = Table_1.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Do While Table_1_reader.Read()
            Submit_ID = Table_1_reader("Submit_ID")
            Control_ID = Table_1_reader("Control_ID")
            If Submit_ID <> Table_1_reader("Submit_ID") Then
                Submit_ID = Table_1_reader("Submit_ID")
                list.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()
                list.SelectCommand.Connection = objConnection
                list.SelectCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (Submit_ID,Form_ID,Control_ID,Row_NO,Table_ID,Int_Val,Decimal_Val,Datetime_Val,String_Val,Boolean_Val) VALUES (" & Submit_ID & ",'" & Form_ID & "," & Control_ID _
& "," & Row_NO & ", '" & Table_ID & ", '" & Int_Val & ", " & Decimal_Val & ", '" & String_Val & ", '" & Boolean_Val & " ' )"
                list.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                list.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
            Select Case Control_ID
                Case 15569
            End Select
        Loop
        Application.DoEvents()
        Table_1_reader.Close()
        objConnection.Close()
        Table_1 = Nothing
        objConnection = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Hi i have this code and i cant handle only one thing.The logic behind this is to get all the data from Table_1 and then convert every row to column in a case situation per control_id.My control_ID get an excact range of values form 15569 to 15578 so for each case of the specific value i wnt to print something like that

> Submit_id       or even better with numbers     1234     1234
>
> controld_id     .....................           15569    15570
>
> form_id     .................................      456        6456
>
> table_id   ........................             23        24
>
> etc....                                         ...

now my databse is like submit_id form_id control_id...so from horizonal i want to go to vertical
any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: sry for the bad format if a moderator can fix it pls do i cant fix it by myself:(

Comment: Sorry, but I'm unclear on  what your actual question is. What is your goal, and what does it do now that doesn't reach that goal?

Comment: @sparkysword I want to modify the data in my table.Now my table is like that. Submit_ID Control _ID Table_ID(Columns names).My purpose is to convert the table so The content Of all Submit iD column will be in the first row of my table and beneath it per submit_ID row[] i will have all the rest columns